# Swoole context empty right after assignment, why?

Tags: php, swoole

I'm trying to use Swoole context and finally have simplifyed it down to the following code

```
$server->on("Start", function(Server $server) 
{
    echo "OpenSwoole WebSocket Server is started at http://127.0.0.1:".config('chat_port')."\n";

    Co::getContext()['total'] = 10;
    var_export(Co::getContext()); 
}
```

var_export prints NULL.
Should the context somehow enabled in configuration or somewhere? Can't google it..

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not reproduce the problem.

```php
$http = new Swoole\Http\Server("127.0.0.1", 9501);
$http->on('request', function ($request, $response) {
    $response->end("<h1>Hello Swoole. #".rand(1000, 9999)."</h1>");
});
$http->on('start', function ($server){
    Co::getContext()['total'] = 10;
    var_dump(Co::getContext());
});
$http->start();
```